# Unable to pip install exceptions Package

Tags: python, pip, installation

When I tried to pip install module exceptions, the error I received was "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement exceptions (from versions:) No matching distribution found for exceptions".
How do I look for the correction version, or is there another option to install this module?

Under the right path where Scripts are saved, I used pip install. Other modules are successfully installed except 'exceptions'

```
pip install --user exceptions
```

Answer (score 6):

There is only [one release](https://pypi.org/project/exceptions/#history) for the module; the release is old (2015), low-quality (version 0.1) and doesn't contain real files to install.

When I go to its home page (repository at Github) I see the module was renamed to [pyception](https://pypi.org/project/pyception/). So install it as:

```
pip install [--user] pyception
```

Comment: Thanks phd. I followed your recommendation and installed pyception but when I run the master file on my computer, I still get the "No module named 'exceptions'" error. Seems like this is a hard requirement.

Comment: The module is also renamed to `pyception`. The old version was never named "exception" — it was [pyexceptions](https://github.com/jonathansp/pyception/commit/1b11dd7486e7f44af721c3df00b3f7c56bd401cf) from the beginning. What code imports "exceptions"?

Comment: the module docx does import exceptions for example: 

line 30: from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
However it's not critically important.

Comment: @Marco `PendingDeprecationWarning` is a builtin exception. Builtin module `exceptions`:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#PendingDeprecationWarning . Do not confuse it with `pip`-installable https://pypi.org/project/exceptions/ Same name, different modules. `Docx` imports the former, the question was about the latter.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I had actually taken a look at the wrong one. :)